# Data from array, need message for each column option not listed in any row (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm pretty much an amateur and I'm stuck on a problem and would greatly appreciate your help.

To give you and example of what I'm trying to achieve: 
One of my columns is 'table_name' (column options: 31,32,33,34,35,36 currently).
Three of the rows in my table have 'table_name' 31 and 34, so they are displayed, no problem so far. But since no rows 'table_name' have the value of '32,32,33,35,36' i would like each to print an individual message ('no tables with number x..' or something like that). And to make matters even more complicated, rows that have other values but empty of 'table_name' should still be displayed.

For a couple of days now I've been racking my brain over how to get this done, so far I've tried using 'else if' and currently 'switch case'. Though I now realize the latter is probably not going to cut it, this is my code currently:

```
foreach ($data as $key) {
    $test = $key['table_name'];
        switch ($test) {
            case 31:
                $html .= '<tr>
                    <td class="bg-blue">31</td> 
                    <td class="bg-blue">4</td>
                    <td>'.$key['reserve_time'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$key['guest_num'].'</td> 
                    <td>'.$key['first_name'].' '.$key['last_name'].'</td> 
                    <td>'.$key['telephone'].'</td> 
                    <td>'.$key['theatre'].'</td> 
                    <td>'.$key['theatre_time'].'</td> 
                    <td>'.$key['comment'].'</td>
                    </tr>';
                    break;
                    case 32:
                    $html .= '<tr>
                    <td class="bg-blue">32</td> 
                    <td class="bg-blue">4</td>
                    <td>'.$key['reserve_time'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$key['guest_num'].'</td> 
                    <td>'.$key['first_name'].' '.$key['last_name'].'</td> 
                    <td>'.$key['telephone'].'</td> 
                    <td>'.$key['theatre'].'</td> 
                    <td>'.$key['theatre_time'].'</td> 
                    <td>'.$key['comment'].'</td>
                    </tr>';
                    break;
                    case 34:
                    $html .= '<tr>
                    <td class="bg-blue">34</td> 
                    <td class="bg-blue">2</td>
                    <td>'.$key['reserve_time'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$key['guest_num'].'</td> 
                    <td>'.$key['first_name'].' '.$key['last_name'].'</td> 
                    <td>'.$key['telephone'].'</td> 
                    <td>'.$key['theatre'].'</td> 
                    <td>'.$key['theatre_time'].'</td> 
                    <td>'.$key['comment'].'</td>
                    </tr>';
                    break;
                }
            }

            echo $html;
```

Which displays this:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sek3A.jpg)

So as you can see from the image the 3 rows with some value in 'table_name' are getting fetched but nothing is displayed for 32 (there is nothing in the code that would do, this is just to give you a general idea). I though i could achieve this using the 'default' case but I´ll still need an individual message for each 'table_name'. Any ideas?

Using Codeigniter 3.1.9 and PHP 7.

I hope I've been clear enough, if not please let me know and I'll try and explain better.

Thank you in advance for your time and help.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your table, it is difficult to visualize the table from what you have written.

Comment: Do you need to show "empty" items on order? What's that "4", "4" and "2" next to "31", "32" and "34"? Show you table (and related tables) structure.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. Here is my table: [link](https://imgur.com/a/1v2Hqoz)